# Marginal effects plot of PLM

Tags: r, plot, plm, marginal-effects

I’ve run an individual-fixed effects panel model in R using the plm-package. I now want to plot the marginal effects.
However, neither plot_model() nor effect_plot() work for plm-objects. plot_model() works for type = “est” but not for type = “pred”.
My online search so far only suggests using ggplot (which however only displays OLS-regressions, not fixed effects) or outdated functions (i.e, sjp.lm())

Does anyone have any recommendations how I can visualize effects of plm-objects?

```
IFE_Aut_uc <- plm(LoC_Authorities_rec ~ Compassion_rec, index = c("id","wave"), model = "within", effect = "individual", data = D3_long2)
summary(IFE_Aut_uc)

plot_model(IFE_Aut_uc, type = "pred”)

Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 50238, 82308
```

and:

```
effect_plot(IFE_Pol_uc, pred = Compassion_rec)

Error in `stop_wrap()`:
! ~does not appear to be a one- or two-sided formula.
LoC_Politicians_recdoes not appear to be a one- or two-sided formula.
Compassion_recdoes not appear to be a one- or two-sided formula.
Backtrace:
 1. jtools::effect_plot(IFE_Pol_uc, pred = Compassion_rec)
 2. jtools::get_data(model, warn = FALSE)
 4. jtools:::get_lhs(formula)
```

Comment: Could you please share some code you tried and data using `dput`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit 2022-08-20: The latest version of `plm` on CRAN now includes a `predict()` method for within models. In principle, the commands illustrated below using `fixest` should now work with `plm` as well.

In my experience, `plm` models are kind of tricky to deal with, and many of the packages which specialize in “post-processing” fail to handle these objects properly.

One alternative would be to estimate your “within” model using [the `fixest` package](https://lrberge.github.io/fixest/) and to plot the results using [the `marginaleffects` package.](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/) (Disclaimer: I am the `marginaleffects` author.)

Note that many of the models estimated by `plm` are officially supported and tested with `marginaleffects` (e.g., random effects, Amemiya, Swaymy-Arora). However, this is not the case of this specific "within" model, which is even trickier than the others to support.

First, we estimate two models to show that the `plm` and `fixest` versions are equivalent:

```r
library(plm)
library(fixest)
library(marginaleffects)
library(modelsummary)
data("EmplUK")

mod1 <- plm(
    emp ~ wage * capital,
    index = c("firm", "year"),
    model = "within",
    effect = "individual",
    data = EmplUK)

mod2 <- feols(
    emp ~ wage * capital | firm,
    se = "standard",
    data = EmplUK)

models <- list("PLM" = mod1, "FIXEST" = mod2)

modelsummary(models)
```

|  | PLM | FIXEST |
| --- | --- | --- |
| wage | 0.000 | 0.000 |
|  | (0.034) | (0.034) |
| capital | 2.014 | 2.014 |
|  | (0.126) | (0.126) |
| wage × capital | -0.043 | -0.043 |
|  | (0.004) | (0.004) |
| Num.Obs. | 1031 | 1031 |
| R2 | 0.263 | 0.986 |
| R2 Adj. | 0.145 | 0.984 |
| R2 Within |  | 0.263 |
| R2 Within Adj. |  | 0.260 |
| AIC | 4253.9 | 4253.9 |
| BIC | 4273.7 | 4273.7 |
| RMSE | 1.90 | 1.90 |
| Std.Errors |  | IID |
| FE: firm |  | X |

Now, we use the `marginaleffects` package to plot the results. There are two main functions for this:

1. `plot_cap()`: plot conditional adjusted predictions. How does my predicted outcome change as a function of a covariate?
2. `plot_cme()`: plot conditional marginal effects. How does the *slope* of my model with respect to one variable (i.e., a derivative or “marginal effect”) change with respect to another variable?

See the website for definitions and details: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/

```r
plot_cap(mod2, condition = "capital")
```

[image]

```r
plot_cme(mod2, effect = "wage", condition = "capital")
```

[image]

Comment: Why would it be hard to support plm's within model when the same model is supported for fixest? Something missing in the model object?

Comment: IIRC, the `predict()` method shipped by the `plm` package is either not working at all, or it doesn't support making predictions on a new dataset (the `newdata` argument). `fixest` makes very different objects, even if it is the same underlying statistical model, so one `predict` method won't work for the other.

Comment: This is extremely helpful for plotting the model! Do you have any guidance on how I can edit the plot (e.g., change axis labels, y-axis range, add title?)

Comment: @Vicent: there is a full `predict` implementation in the development version: https://github.com/ycroissant/plm

Comment: @luca the result of these functions is a normal `ggplot2` object, so you can use all the same customizing functions. Also, you can set `draw=FALSE` if you just want the data and want to do a fully customized plot. See here for some customization examples. https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/predictions.html#conditional-adjusted-predictions-plot

Comment: @Helix123 This is wonderful news, thanks! I just tried it and with the dev version of `plm`, the `marginaleffects` package commands seem to work automatically as expected.

Comment: One little to remark: your `plot_cap` / `plot_cme` examples for the fixest model only run if the model was estimated with a pdata.frame (or likely more precise, with the panel identifiers as factors) -> `mod2 <- feols(emp ~ wage * capital | firm,  se = "standard", data = pdata.frame(EmplUK))` to make it reproducible on my end.

Comment: No, that's incorrect. I just replicated on my machine without loading `plm` at all, and by reading the data in memory from a CSV file:  https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/plm/EmplUK.csv

Comment: Maybe we are both right: on my end, it is not reproducible for the fixest model with the current CRAN version 0.6.0 of `marginaleffects` while it is with the current dev version 0.6.0.9000 (e10acc2) (I just tried this one)

Comment: Ha! Sorry about that. I just always with the dev version so I missed this! Thanks for taking the time to investigate and report. I'll try to be less cut-and-dry in future responses ;)

Comment: No worries! Btw: version 2.6-2 of plm incl. the `predict` functions is on CRAN since a few days.

Comment: Great news! I edited my answer at the top to note that the code should also work with `plm` and that my warning is obsolete.